# I'm matching a string and want to return the next three lines after the match

Tags: regex, string, perl, line, match

I'm matching a string and want to return the next three lines after the match.
I know that $_ will return the line but I'm not sure what expression to use to return the next two lines in the file that I have.
Here the code I have:

```
open my $fh, '>', "${file}result.txt" or die $!;
       $fh->print("$file\t$_\n");
       print "$_\n";
```

Thanks in advance for the help and not making too much fun.

Comment: `grep -A 3` is exactly what you want for what it is worth.

Comment: how would I place that into my code above? Instead of print "$_\n";  - How do I print what the grep gets?

Comment: Try using $. which gives the current line number and from there try to get the next 2 or 3 lines using a condition.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple:

```
while (<$infile>)
{
    if (/REGEX/)
    {
        $outfile->print($_);
        $outfile->print($infile->getline) for 0 .. 1;
    }
}
```

The `IO::Handle` methods are nice for a couple of reasons. `$infile->getline` is like `<>`, but only ever grabs one line (whereas `<>` will return all lines in list context). It also doesn't clobber `$_` or warn at the end of the file (although sometimes the latter behavior is desirable).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (FH, "input.txt") or die $!;

my @contents = <FH>;
my $count = 0;

map
{
   $count ++;
   if($_ =~ /This/)
   {
       print "\nNext 3 lines:\n$contents[$count+1] $contents[$count+2] $contents[$count+3]";
   }
} @contents;
```

This Will do it.

Thanks.

Comment: This will build two copies of the file in memory, one to store in the array and another by `map`. Both can be avoided by iterating over the file with a `while` loop, reading one line at a time.

Comment: Plus it is darn hard to read.  Write your code for people to read. The compiler will look after itself.