# Print array elements dynamically using range

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-data-structures

I have the following code:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

open (FH, "input.txt") or die $!;

my @contents = <FH>;
my $count = 0;

map
{
   $count ++;
   if($_ =~ /This/)
   {
       print "\nNext 3 lines:\n$contents[$count+1] $contents[$count+2] $contents[$count+3]";
   }
} @contents;
```

Summary of program:
1. Get an input file.
2. If the line contains 'This', then print the next 3 lines.

I was wondering how can I modify the print statement to show the array contents using range.
That is, something like below:

```
print "\nNext 3 lines:\n$contents[$count..$count+3]";
```

Can anyone point out what is the right way to achieve this?

PS: My problem here is in showing array range. Please don't discuss the efficiency of the program.

Comment: `print @contents[$count..$count+3]` or something like that? or join array elements

Comment: `print join "\n", @contents[$count+1..$count+3];` to join the array slice elements.

Comment: BTW, this question was asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476583/im-matching-a-string-and-want-to-return-the-next-three-lines-after-the-match -- please search for answers before creating a new question.

Comment: @ialarmedalien This is answer to that question. I has some queries when answering that. That is what I have put here. Please look into intention of my question. My question is on array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax that you want is

```
@contents[$count..$count+3]
```

It's called an array slice.

But you probably want something like:

```
@contents[$count..min($count+3, $#count)]
```

to avoid falling off the end of the array.

And please don't use `map` in void context like that. If you're not using the return value from `map` then `foreach` (or `for`) is far less confusing for the people who need to maintain your code later (even if that's you in two weeks time).

**Update:** In the comments, @DaveVogt just pointed out that your count starts from 1 rather that the more common 0. The easiest way to get round that is probably to move the `$count++` to the end of the loop body.

So here's how I'd write it (well, it's probably not how I'd write it at all - but it's how I'd write it starting from your version).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util 'min';

open my $in_fh, 'input.txt' or die $!;

my @contents = <$in_fh>;
my $count = 0;

foreach (@contents) {
  if (/This/) {
    next if $count >= $#contents;
    my $end = min($count+3, $#contents);
    print "\nNext three lines: @contents[$count+1..$end]";
  }
  $count++;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be $@contents instead of $#count?

Comment: Hmm... well, perhaps just `@contents`. I hadn't noticed that the counter started from 1. I'll update it.

Comment: @DaveCross- That was very useful. Thanks. 
Regarding the void context you were talking about, I found a page related to that saying map/grep in void context is not expensive from Perl V 5.8.1.
If you are talking from reader's perspective, then its OK.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174492/in-perl-is-it-appropriate-to-use-map-in-void-context-instead-of-a-foreach-loop

Comment: That's right. It's no longer inefficient to use `map` in a void context - which is why I didn't suggest that it was. The problem is that your maintenance programmer (who may well be you in three months time) will expect `map` to be used in list context. When it isn't, it has potential to be confusing. If you're ever tempted to use `map` in void context I strongly recommend that you use `foreach` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @lines = ('one', 'two', 'This line', 'That line', 'Other line', 'Last line', 'three', 'four');

my $count = 0;

foreach(@lines){
    $count = 4 if /This/;
    print "$_\n" if ($count-- > 0);
}
```

On reading through your array this will set `$count` to `4` on encountering a `This`, and will print the line until `$count -1` is > 0 (i.e. the first incidence prints the line itself, and then the next 3 lines)

Comment: Please consider writing a few lines about what/why was wrong in the original code. Even if that's trivial, it can help novices in understanding that.